# QGIS- Widget Photo Attachment do not show photo (small pix)

Tags: qgis, image, attachments

I have attached photos with their file path in the column. And I have set the height and width of the photo. but it does not work to show the photo on the attribute table. 
[image]

and this is when I show the attribute table with Identify Features icon in QGIS. but the photo that I attached on attribute table just show in a small size although I set photo height and width wit 500px each. you can see the screenshot below.
[image]

Can any one fix this problem?

Comment: fyi: when I use another version of QGIS (2.18.28), I can show a full image according to width and height that I have set before.